# I am writing the codes in the multi-image upload process, but when I go to the path I gave, it does not add?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, image, asp.net-core

I want to upload more than one image, but even though I have many loops, it does not add an error on the insert screen. The codes are below. How can I fix this problem?

I guess there is a problem in the else case in the backend codes, when I give the path there, it cannot perform the insertion operation.

```js
  $(function () {
        const url = '/Admin-Urunmamul/Create/';
        const placeHolderDiv = $('#modalPlaceHolder');
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            $.get(url).done(function (data) {
                placeHolderDiv.html(data);
                placeHolderDiv.find(".modal").modal('show');
            });
        });

        /* Ajax GET / Getting the _CategoryAddPartial as Modal Form ends here. */

        /* Ajax POST / Posting the FormData as CategoryAddDto starts from here. */

        placeHolderDiv.on('click',
            '#btnUrunmamulSave',
            function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const form = $('#form-urunmamul-add');
                const actionUrl = form.attr('action');
                const dataToSend = new FormData(form.get(0));
                $.ajax({
                    url: actionUrl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dataToSend,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        const urunmamulAddAjaxModel = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        const newFormBody = $('.modal-body', urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulAddPartial);
                        placeHolderDiv.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newFormBody);
                        const isValid = newFormBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val() === 'True';
                        if (isValid) {
                            placeHolderDiv.find('.modal').modal('hide');
                            let rowData = [
                                urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.KOD,
                                urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.ACIKLAMA1,
                                urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.ACIKLAMA2,
                                urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.TUR,
                                urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.CINS,
                                urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.ETIKET18K,
                                urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.ETIKET14K,
                                urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.DOVIZ,
                                urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.BITMISGRAM,
                                `<td style="text-align:center"><img width="120" height="120" multiple class="align-middle" asp-append-version="true" src="${'http://paramdiamond.com/Resim/MODEL/'+urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.RESIMX}" /></td>`,
                                `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-update" data-id="${urunmamulAddAjaxModel
                                    .UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.ID}"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></button> `,
                                `<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete" data-id="${urunmamulAddAjaxModel
                                    .UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.ID}"><span class="fas fa-minus-circle"></span></button>`
                            ];

                            const newTableRow = dataTable.row.add(rowData).node();
                            const jqueryTableRow = $(newTableRow);
                            jqueryTableRow.attr('name', `${urunmamulAddAjaxModel.UrunMamulDto.Urunmamul.ID}`);
                            dataTable.row(jqueryTableRow).draw();
                            toastr.success('Ürün eklendi.', 'Başarılı İşlem!');
                        } else {
                            let summaryText = "";
                            $('#validation-summary > ul > li').each(function () {
                                let text = $(this).text();
                                summaryText = `*${text}\n`;
                            });
                            toastr.warning(summaryText);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        toastr.error(`${err.responseText}`, 'Hata!');
                    }
                });

            });
    });
```

```html
<form asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="AdminUrunMamul" asp-action="Create" id="form-urunmamul-add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="UrunMamulAddDto.RESIMXFile"></label>
                        <input multiple asp-for="UrunMamulAddDto.RESIMXFile" type="file" class="form-control-file" />
                        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="UrunMamulAddDto.RESIMXFile"></span>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

```
if (urunMamul.UrunMamulAddDto.RESIMXFile != null && urunMamul.UrunMamulAddDto.RESIMXFile.Count > 0)
                    {

                        string path = @"C:\inetpub\B2B\ParamDiamond\RESIM\MODEL\" + urunMamul.UrunMamulAddDto.KOD + ".jpg";
                        IFormFileCollection files = Request.Form.Files;
                        files.ToList().ForEach(file =>
                        {
                            Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images");
                            if (file.Length > 0)
                                //using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(@"C:\inetpub\B2B\ParamDiamond\RESIM\MODEL\", urun.KOD + ".jpg"), FileMode.Create))
                                //{
                                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                                {
                                    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
                                    {
                                        path = @"C:\inetpub\B2B\ParamDiamond\RESIM\MODEL\" + urunMamul.UrunMamulAddDto.KOD + "_" + i + ".jpg";
                                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path) == false)
                                        {
                                            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(@"C:\inetpub\B2B\ParamDiamond\RESIM\MODEL\", urunMamul.UrunMamulAddDto.KOD + "_" + i + ".jpg"), FileMode.Create))
                                            {
                                                file.CopyTo(stream);
                                            }
                                            //file.CopyTo(stream);
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(@"C:\inetpub\B2B\ParamDiamond\RESIM\MODEL\", urunMamul.UrunMamulAddDto.KOD + ".jpg"), FileMode.Create))
                                    {
                                        file.CopyTo(stream);

                                    }
                                }
                            //}
                        });
                    }
```